# curl with file upload to python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, curl

I am trying to convert the following curl to a python request. This request uploads a zip file.

```
curl -k -i -X POST --form 'session.id=e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e' --form 'ajax=upload' --form 'file=@myproject.zip;type=application/zip' --form 'project=MyProject' https://localhost:8443/manager
```

Using curl to python convertor tool - I got this

```
import requests

files = {
    'session.id': (None, 'e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e'),
    'ajax': (None, 'upload'),
    'file': ('myproject.zip;type', open('myproject.zip;type', 'rb')),
    'project': (None, 'MyProject'),
}

response = requests.post('https://localhost:8443/manager', files=files, verify=False)
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try separating data and files:

```
import requests

data = {
    "ajax": "upload",
    "project": "MyProject",
    "session.id": "e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e",
}

files = {"file": ("myproject.zip", open("myproject.zip", "rb"), "application/zip")}

response = requests.post("https://localhost:8443/manager", data=data, verify=False, files=files)
```